Yarn 4.3.1 says a package (typescript-eslint) doesn't provide another (typescript) to its dependencies
After installing some packages with yarn 4.3.1 it says:

Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met by dependencies; run yarn explain peer-requirements for details.

After running yarn explain peer-requirements says:
...
(dependencies working)
...
pd8655 → ✘ @typescript-eslint/utils@npm:7.17.0 [eb8b2] doesn't provide typescript to @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@npm:7.17.0 [05a60] and 1 other dependency
...
(dependencies working)
...

And after running yarn explain peer-requirements pd8655 says:
Package @typescript-eslint/utils@npm:7.17.0 [eb8b2] is requested to provide typescript by its descendants

@typescript-eslint/utils@npm:7.17.0 [eb8b2]
└─ @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@npm:7.17.0 [05a60] (via *)
   └─ ts-api-utils@npm:1.3.0 [b4f1c] (via >=4.2.0)

✘ Package @typescript-eslint/utils@npm:7.17.0 [eb8b2] does not provide typescript.

This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "backend-ts",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.3.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/eslint": "^9.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.5",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "typescript-eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

As you can see, I already have installed Typescript and typescript-eslint documentation says my typescript version is in the correct range.
Do you know what's happening, and how can I fix it?

I was getting the same error when scaffolding a new Vite project.  There are some compatibility issues with the package versions that you are using.  I managed to get the following installed with no warnings; the output was:
PS C:\Projects\test> yarn install
➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.1.1
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0085: │ + @eslint/js@npm:9.8.0, @types/eslint@npm:9.6.0, @types/eslint__js@npm:8.42.3, @types/node@npm:22.0.0, @types/webpack@npm:5.28.5, eslint-config-prettier@npm:9.1.0, eslint-webpack-plugin@npm:4.2.0, eslint@npm:9.8.0, prettier@npm:3.3.3, and 255 more.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 92ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 260ms
➤ YN0000: · Done with warnings in 1s 577ms

I used the following packages in the Package.json:
{
  "name": "test",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.1.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.8.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^9.6.0",
    "@types/eslint__js": "^8.42.3",
    "@types/node": "^22.0.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.5",
    "eslint": "^9.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4",
    "typescript-eslint": "8.0.0-alpha.10",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}

For reference:
PS C:\Projects\test> node --version
v20.13.1
PS C:\Projects\test> npm --version
10.5.2
PS C:\Projects\test> yarn --version
4.1.1

The above was created by creating a new folder, running yarn init in the command-line followed by
yarn add --dev @eslint/js@^9.8.0 @types/eslint@^9.6.0 @types/eslint__js@^8.42.3 @types/node@^22.0.0 @types/webpack@^5.28.5 eslint@^9.8.0 eslint-config-prettier@^9.1.0 eslint-webpack-plugin@^4.2.0 prettier@^3.3.3 ts-loader@^9.5.1 ts-node@^10.9.2 typescript@^5.5.4 typescript-eslint@8.0.0-alpha.10 webpack@^5.93.0 webpack-cli@^5.1.4

Hope this helps.

This is a known issue with typescript-esilnt. You can use a package extension to add the missing peer dependency:
packageExtensions:
  "@typescript-eslint/utils@*":
    peerDependenciesMeta:
      typescript:
        optional: true

